# Why was this post marked as Spam?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, spam, specific-answer

I came across this review audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5741371 which I apparently didn't pass as I selected "Looks good".

While the answer (and the question) in this case certainly isn't one of the best on StackOverflow, it certainly isn't spam. The link given in the answer goes to the canonical website of an open source Python tool specifically designed for the task asked. As such, while I absolutely sympathize with the question being closed, I doubt that the answer is spam. It links the OP to a helpful place and provides a (very) brief description of the tool. The website doesn't promote anything shady and certainly doesn't include any offensive language.

Therefore, my question is: Why was this answer marked as spam by @BilltheLizard and why did it merit the inclusion as a review audit?

Comment: It's only content is to promote an external tool. It is entirely possible that the only thing that account did is to post that as an "answer" to multiple questions.

Comment: It wasn't marked as spam by Bill the Lizard. He would have deleted the post *responding to flags*. The **system** then marks it as a deleted spam post due to the flags.

Comment: Hmmm, the "posting to multiple answers" reason would certainly explain the Spam delete here. Although, in this case, the answer alone is definitely on-topic and non spam standing on it's own.

Comment: The question was entirely off-topic and shouldn't have been answered in the first place. The answer itself is also pretty useless.

Comment: The question is crap, there you are right. While the answer is not very good either, it is still **not spam**. It might probably be deleted as being VLQ or even for answering a bad question, but not as Spam on its own.

Comment: It was *flagged* as spam, and thus auto-marked as such when deleted and no other flags were active against it.

Comment: Is that even marked as spam now? When I view the deleted answer it's not making me click through to the history to see the content, like with most spam/offensive material.

Comment: @Wooble: The spam flag has been cleared from the post. See [Brad's comment on my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271126/why-was-this-post-marked-as-spam/271127?noredirect=1#comment92995_271127).

Comment: "Looks good?"  *Looks good???*  Lordy.

Comment: @Will: It was *not* spam and could be improved by a quick edit afterwards. I agree that it's borderline to a closable link-only question, but it could very well stand on it's own. The link is relevant (for both the tool and the language). And explaining a whole library in an answer probably doesn't add much.

Comment: "Looks good"? If you actually think so, please stop doing reviews; you're not helping things here. (The answer wasn't spam, but it was by no means a valid answer here. There's no meaningful content **here**, just an unsolicited post to an external site. The answer becomes entirely worthless if that off-site link is unavailable for some reason, which is precisely why we *highly discourage* answers consisting of nothing but external links.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The total content of the post was:

```
Fabric http://www.fabfile.org/ is an excellent tool for programming tasks over ssh protocol.

Best regards.
```

This is not a useful answer anywhere; it was then flagged as spam (it is promoting an external tool, unsolicited). Judging by the downvote count there was just the one flag.

A moderator then responded to the flag by deleting the post. When that happens and the *majority* of flags are spam flags, the post is automatically transformed to show it was a deleted spam post. This is not a decision the moderator makes, it is entirely automatic.

Apart from it being not useful, it was also **not** *Look[ing] Good* for other reasons. It has a useless valediction at the end; the *Best regards* part is noise that you could have edited out.

Comment: The OP asked for a tool to programmatically log into a remote server (presumedly via SSH). Thus, the answer is on-topic in my eyes. With this reason, you could delete about any question linking to an existing library solving a question.

Comment: @HolgerJust: it was a 'write code for me' question. Mentioning an external tool to solve a problem is fine, but *not if that is the only thing you mention*. An answer like that should at the very least explain better how that tool would be used in such a case.

Comment: @HolgerJust You are correct that the question is a very bad question.  It's already been closed, and it can probably be deleted at this point.  That doesn't make the answer not spam though, it just means that the duteous reviewer wouldn't stop there.

Comment: It also had a "very low quality" flag on it, which is what Bill might have seen during review. It was flagged as spam by another user, so when Bill deleted the post in response to the other flag it automatically validated the spam flag and made this an audit case. I've cleared the spam flag so that this will not be an audit case for that going forward, but it still might be used as an audit due to the validated low quality flag.

Comment: @BradLarson: right, so it was still 50% spam. IIRC it would not mark it as deleted spam if the percentage drops below 50.

Comment: Even if Bill hadn't acted on it, it was one vote short of being deleted from review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5626208 which would have ended up with the same result.

Comment: Okay, so it's probably just bad luck that it turned up as spam. Thanks for the explanation. So I guess, it's just another +1 from me to a more restrictive selection of audit tasks. Still, I think, the answer is still borderline okay and wouldn't have merited an outright delete. It's not very good but not fully crap either...

Comment: @HolgerJust - I'll once again promote this proposal: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/135615 which I think would deal with problematic audits without imposing too much new work on everyone involved.

Comment: @Brad Larson: Quit spamming!